# How can we solve unexpected tocken error in mongo shell command?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

In my test server I am using mongo shell version `2.6.10`. When I run below command (it is for update datatype from string to float). I am getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.

In mongo shell version `3.4.4` it is working.

```
var ops = [];
    db.booking.find({prepayment_amount: {$exists: true}}).forEach(doc => {
                doc.prepayment_amount = parseFloat(doc.prepayment_amount) || 0;

                ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
                    "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
          "update": {
                        "$set": { "prepayment_amount": doc.prepayment_amount }
          }
        }
      });

      if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
          db.booking.bulkWrite(ops);
          ops = [];
      }
    });

    if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
        db.booking.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
```

Comment: remove this line and try again `                doc.prepayment_amount = parseFloat(doc.prepayment_amount) || 0;`. See which line of code is causing the error and try to find for which value or record. It may be failing on a specific case

Comment: `doc =>` is not recognized by the older shell because it's ES6 syntax that was not available to the V8 build that the shell and server implement on that version. Use regular JavaScript functions instead `function(doc)` instead of the ES6 arrow syntax.

Comment: I might add that there is absolutely no reason why your MongoDB 3.4.4 "shell" cannot be used to connect to a MongoDB 2.6 server. I also should add that 2.6.x releases are at "end of life" for official support. You should be upgrading to 2.8.x at the very least, and preferably a 3.x release.

Comment: I have rewrite the code like this please check and correct me `db.booking.find({prepayment_amount: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    x.prepayment_amount = parseFloat(x.prepayment_amount) || 0;
    db.booking.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {prepayment_amount: x.prepayment_amount}});
});`  Now the error is not showing but I am not sure is this a correct script.